# Returning float in Integer return type

Tags: c++, function, type-conversion

What is the reason why the program is not showing an error and converting 0.05f to 0?

```
int main()
{
  int a,b;
  cin>>a>>b;
  cout<<a+b;
  return 0.05f;
}
```

Comment: An implicit `float` to `int` conversion exists, so that would be a warning at best. Are you compiling with warnings enabled?

Comment: Please do not use the [c] tag for C++ questions.

Comment: What would you have expected the program to return?

Comment: @JohnDibling I think OP expected a compilation error.

Comment: Why did you decide to include the first three lines of the function?

Comment: @JohnDibling I was expecting an error, but when there wasn't any I started looking for a reason.

Comment: Got it.  Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are implicitly typecasting `float` to `int` that's as per c++ standard - but i believe if you turn on your compiler warnings, you will get a warning for this.

When i do this in VS2012, i get warning:

```
Warning 1   warning C4244: 'return' : conversion from 'float' to 'int', possible loss of data
```

Comment: I'm using TurboC++ and the compiler is not even showing any warnings.

Comment: But is there any problem in TurboC++ , 'cause it didn't even show a warning.

Comment: Change Compiler !! use Visual Studio on Windows or GCC on Linux/ubuntu. Please Vote UP and mark answer as Accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new can't vote an answer now ( You need to have 15 Repo for that ). But will surely vote up ASAP :)

Comment: By the way  . .Thanks . . still will try to find out whats with TurboC++.

Comment: Oh... no worries then. remember to vote for all answers once you get 15 rep. That's only thing people at stackoverflow expect :) Moreover, try to change TurboC++.

Answer (score 2):

You'd get a warning (probably) but not an error, because the implicit conversion is legal:

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'float' to 'int' changes value from 0.050000001 to 0 [-Wliteral-conversion]
```

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard has conversion rules for converting `float` to `int`, so it's perfectly fine to do that. It should compile, but you may get warnings.

Section 4.9, point 1 of n3337 version of C++11 standard:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an
>   integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part
>   is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot
>   be represented in the destination type